# Java chained map of collections

Tags: java, collections, types, dictionary

I have a list of `Things`, which each have a *category* (an `int`). What I want to end up with is a Map, where the key is the category, and the value is a List of all of the `Things` of that *category*. At the moment I'm having to do this fairly manually, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of type that I'm not aware of.

At present I do something like the following:

```
List<Thing> things = thingGenerator.generateTheThings();
Map<Integer,List<Thing>> categoriesOfThing = new TreeMap<Integer,List<Thing>>();

for(Thing thing : things) {
    int thingCategory = thing.getCategory();
    List<Thing> oneCategoryOfThing;
    if(categoriesOfThing.containsKey(thingCategory) {
        oneCategoryOfThing = categoriessOfThings.get(thingCategory);
    }
    else {
        oneCategoryOfThing = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    }

    oneCategoryOfThing.add(thing);
    categoriesOfThing.put(thingCategory,oneCategoryOfThing);
}

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCategories; i++) {
    List<Thing> similarThings = categoriesOfThing.get(i);
    foo(similarThings);
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something a bit like the following:

```
List<Thing> things = thingGenerator.generateTheThings();
ChainedMap<Integer,Thing> categoriesOfThing = new ChainedMap<Integer,Thing>();

for(Thing thing : things) {
    categoriesOfThing.add(thing.getCategory(), thing);
}

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTypes; i++) {
    List<Thing> similarThings = categoriesOfThing.get(i);
    foo(similarThings);
}
```

Much like the [Apache MultiKey](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/collections/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) allows for multiple keys to be used in a map, I'd like multiple values to be retrievable in a `List`.

Comment: Is your Thing a template class? i.e, `Thing<int>`

Comment: No, it just contains data and a few trivial methods.

Comment: OK, so when you say "the value is a List of all of the `Thing`s of that *type*" you mean you're doing the lookup by value, rather than by type?  The way you worded that threw me into thinking you were looking for something like `Map<Class<T>, List<Thing<T> >` (which probably isn't the correct syntax)

Comment: @Wug Sorry, I didn't mean 'type' in that way. It's just a property of the Thing (This is a disadvantage of having to remove the context of this code, I guess). I've updated the examples above to use the word 'category' instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been suggested elsewhere in the comments that the OP should use Guava -- among other things, it provides generics, unlike the linked Apache documentation -- so here's the Guava solution.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

```
 ListMultimap<Integer, Thing> multimap =
   Multimaps.index(listOfThings, new Function<Thing, Integer>() {
     public Integer apply(Thing thing) {
       return thing.getCategory();
     }
   });
```

Or, if you want to do it explicitly instead of using `Multimaps.index`, it's possibly even simpler:

```
 ListMultimap<Integer, Thing> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
 for (Thing t : listOfThings) {
    multimap.put(t.getCategory(), t);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having discovered the Apache MultiKey, trawling the documentation revealed the [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html), which appears to do what I want.

> A MultiMap is a Map with slightly different semantics. Putting a value
>   into the map will add the value to a Collection at that key. Getting a
>   value will always return a Collection, holding all the values put to
>   that key. This implementation uses an ArrayList as the collection.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
>     mhm.put(key, "A");
>     mhm.put(key, "B");
>     mhm.put(key, "C");
>     Collection coll = mhm.get(key);
> ```
>
> `coll` will be a list containing "A", "B", "C".

Comment: Go for Guava and its MultiMap - it's mostly the same as this1 from Apache, but you will have an oportunity to get to know that awsome library.